# React Link and React Route: Trying to clear the page but appending is occurring instead? Very weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a very basic blog website and I have a part where I'm on a Main Blog page. And there is a button that uses `<Link>` and `<Route>` to go to a specific blog post. However when it is clicked it appends the information from the specific blog post to the Main Blog page instead of clearing the page and then going into the specific blog post information. I'm really confused and I really need the help. I attached my code and screenshots.

Main Blog page

```
import React from 'react';
import './Blog.css';

import { BrowserRouter , Route, Link, Switch, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import TestPage from './TestBlog.js';


function Blog() {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <header>
                <h1> Blog </h1>

                <div class="card">
                  <div class="container">
                    <h4><b> Date 2020 - Date 2020 (My experience)</b></h4> 

                    <NavLink to="/testpage">
                        <button type="button">
                            Read More
                        </button>
                    </NavLink>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <Route path = "/testpage" component = {TestPage} />

            </header>
        </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Blog Post

```
import React from 'react';

function TestBlog() {
 
    return (
        <div>
        <header>

            <h1> Testing </h1>
            <p> Test Description </p>

        </header>
        </div>
    )

}

export default TestBlog
```

This is what is currently occurring.

Before clicking the button to go to the Blog Post (starts off at http://localhost:3000/blog):
[image]

After clicking the button to go to the Blog Post (ends off at http://localhost:3000/testpage, however the information is being appended while instead I want the page to clear/refresh and then display the blog post information):
[image]

Please I'm really confused and really need some help. Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, everything you return will be rendered. Anything that's supposed to sometimes render and sometimes not based on the url needs to be in a `<Route>`. You may also find it useful to use `<Switch>`, which makes sure that only one of its child routes will be rendered even if multiple of them would match otherwise. For example:

```
function Blog() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/testpage" component={TestPage} />
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1> Blog </h1>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="container">
          <h4>
            <b> Date 2020 - Date 2020 (My experience)</b>
          </h4>

          <NavLink to="/testpage">
            <button type="button">Read More</button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

So in this case, there will always be a `<BrowserRouter>`, and there will always be a `<div>`. Inside that div, if the url matches "/testpage", it will show the TestPage component. Otherwise, the HomePage component will be shown

Comment: You are a god. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey I wanted to ask, if I wanted to do a back button in my Blog Post code how would I do that? Would I do the same <Switch> method that you have or another way?

Comment: Get the history object with `const history = useHistory()`. Then when the click happens, call `history.goBack()`